# PHP website "pending" response with PHP 8.0 LSPHP in browsers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I maintain a custom legacy PHP website. The hosting provided recently upgraded the PHP version to 8.0 (from 7.3) that worked generally fine. Now they switched the PHP version used from 8.0 to 8.0 LSPHP with `.htaccess` setting:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

As a result, the website does not load in browsers: you see only a blank screen, no error messages and the dev tools report the response to be pending, like the response is in progress. The same page can be retrieved with `curl` without errors.

I have only seen an error message with the old IE, there it said: "We connected to the website, but didn’t receive any data from it. Error Code: INET_E_DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE".

I have fixed the problem by reverting back to PHP 7.4 LSPHP, where it works again, but I would like to understand what is the problem of my site with PHP 8.0.

My guess is that 8.0 LSPHP enabled some transport method that the browsers would like to use, but they cannot. As `curl` does not use this option it works there. But I have no idea what this option could be and how to fix it.

Does anyone have any hints or keywords to search for?

Comment: LSPHP is for the LiteSpeed webserver, but this has been tagged `apache`. So which server _is_ your hosting platform actually running?

Comment: @CBroe Thx for the note. I assumed it is `apache`, in the response headers there is a `server: Apache`. Is there an easy way to figure out what it is really? The LSPHP setting wasn't chosen by me, this is what the hosing provider sets in `.htaccess` if I choose PHP 8.0 on their cpanel. It is JustHost btw. I also tried to set it back to "normal" 8.0 (like it was until yesterday), but then all request responses with 404.